# How to split string in PostgreSQL to make combination with another string

Tags: postgresql

I have data like below

```
Id | Data                                                                  |Parent Id
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | IceCream # Chocolate # SoftDrink              |0
2  | Amul,Havemore#Cadbary,Nestle#Pepsi     |1
3  | Party#Wedding                                                |0
```

I want to split this data in below format where row 2 is dependent on row 1. I have added ParentId which is use to find dependency.

```
IceCream  | Amul      | Party
IceCream  | Havemore  | Party
IceCream  | Amul      | Wedding
IceCream  | Havemore  | Wedding
Chocolate | Cadbery   | Party
Chocolate | Nestle    | Party
Chocolate | Cadbery   | Wedding
Chocolate | Nestle    | Wedding
SoftDrink | Pepsi     | Party
SoftDrink | Pepsi     | Wedding
```

I have used `unnest(string_to_array)` to split string but unable to traverse through loop to make this combination.

Comment: Can you post some details of the logic used to obtain that result?

Comment: How do you know which row needs which delimiter to split the values? And where does this "flag" come from that "is known to you"

Comment: I believe you need a larger number of rows to explain your problem. + important: Are there ANY other columns in this table? Please be aware that in SQL tables are "un-ordered sets" so you should not assume that "row 2" will be row encountered after "row 1"; they might be process in a completely different order.

Answer (score 1):

The is a very "unstable",like sitting on a knife edge and could easily fall apart. It depends on assigning values for each delimited value and then joining on those values. Maybe those flags that are known to you (but unfortunately not us) can stabilize it. But it does match your indicated expectations. It uses the function [regexp_split_to_table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-string.html) rather than unnest to split the delimiters.

```
with base (num, list) as 
   ( values (1,'IceCream#Chocolate#SoftDrink')
          , (2,'Amul,Havemore#Cadbary,Nestle#Pepsi')
          , (3,'Party#Wedding')
   )  
   , product as
     (select p, row_number(*) over() pn
        from ( 
              select regexp_split_to_table(list,'#') p
                from base
               where num=1
             ) x
     )
   , maker as
     (select  regexp_split_to_table(m, ',') m, row_number(*) over() mn
        from (
              select regexp_split_to_table(list,'#') m
                from base
               where num=2
             ) y
     )
   , event as
     ( select regexp_split_to_table(regexp_split_to_table(list,'#'), ',') e
         from base
        where num=3
     ) 
select p as product
     , m as maker
     , e as event
  from (product join maker on pn = mn) cross join event e
  order by pn, e, m;
```

Hope it helps.